# Отцентрировать меню

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста отцентрировать меню, сейчас оно находится с левой стороны страницы, нужно что бы оно было по середине.

```
#main-nav {    
    background-color: #294a70;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #C1CDCD;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.main-navigation ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-navigation ul ul {
    background: #294a70 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 44px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul {
    left:100%;
    top: 0;
}


<div id="main-nav" class="clear-fix">
<div class="container">
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
<button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>Menu</button>
<div class="wrap-menu-content">
<div class="menu-menu-container">
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-48"><a href="/">menu1</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/bwdyOL?editors=110  вот так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так с использованием `display: inline-block`:

```css
#main-nav {    
    background-color: #294a70;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #C1CDCD;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.main-navigation ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  
  text-align: center;
}

.main-navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.main-navigation ul ul {
    background: #294a70 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 44px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul {
    left:100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-nav" class="clear-fix">
<div class="container">
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
<button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>Menu</button>
<div class="wrap-menu-content">
<div class="menu-menu-container">
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-48"><a href="/">menu1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Или так с использованием `flex`:

```css
#main-nav {    
    background-color: #294a70;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #C1CDCD;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.main-navigation ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.main-navigation ul ul {
    background: #294a70 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 44px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul {
    left:100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-nav" class="clear-fix">
<div class="container">
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
<button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>Menu</button>
<div class="wrap-menu-content">
<div class="menu-menu-container">
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-48"><a href="/">menu1</a></li>
</ul>
```